# How to keep the original order of input when using ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, threadpoolexecutor

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

def add_one(number, n):
    return number + 1 + n

def process():
    all_numbers = []
    for i in range(0, 10):
        all_numbers.append(i)

    threads = []
    all_results = []
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        for number in all_numbers:
            threads.append(executor.submit(add_one, number))

        for index, task in enumerate(as_completed(threads)):
            result = task.result()
            #print(result)
            all_results.append(result)

    for index, result in enumerate(all_results):
        print(result)

process()
```

If I set max_works=1, it will print out from 1 to 10 in order; if I set max_workers = 10, the order could be random:

```
5
3
10
7
1
8
6
2
4
9
```

How to keep the original order of the input when using ThreadPoolExecutor to process a list of items as in this example?

Comment: If you want a specific execution order why are you using threads?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) method of the ThreadExecutor:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

def add_one(number):
    return number + 1

def process():
    all_numbers = []
    for i in range(0, 10):
        all_numbers.append(i)

    all_results = []
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        for i in executor.map(add_one, all_numbers):
            print(i)
            all_results.append(i)

    for index, result in enumerate(all_results):
        print(result)

process()
```

Updated answer based on comments requirements:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

def add_one(args):
    return args[0] + 1 + args[1]

def process():
    all_numbers = []
    for i in range(0, 10):
        all_numbers.append([i, 2])

    all_results = []
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        for i in executor.map(add_one, all_numbers):
            print(i)
            all_results.append(i)

    for index, result in enumerate(all_results):
        print(result)

process()
```

Comment: My actual add_one() has one more parameter, 'n'. In such a case, how to pass the additional parameter to the executor.map() function along with the all_numbers? I edited the add_one() function.

Comment: @marlon I updated the answer bases on your comments

Comment: Using `repeat` from `itertools` allows you to avoid some of the additional parameter `args` complexity.  It allows `add_one(number, n)` using `map.executor(add_one, all_numbers, itertools.repeat(2))`

Comment: @rhurwitz, does the repeat(2) means there are two parameters for the function add_one?

Comment: @rhurwitz could you write a complete answer? In your comments, should it be map.executor() or executor.map()?

Answer (score 3):

This mixes two incompatible ideas!

When you use a thread/process/whatever pool, the work will be done in an arbitrary order (largely the result of unrelated system load). Some work could happen at the same time as other work, which is normally the benefit of such a system; parallelization! However, unless you go out of your way to order the results, they will be in whatever order the pool did the work in.

Rather than attempting to "order" the results, consider mapping them back to some collection, such as a dictionary, so you can read them back by-key (which may have some order to it).

Answer (score 3):

Just remove `as_completed` from your code!

`executor.submit` will return `Future` object, and you append it to list in order.

But `as_completed` will generate `Future` objects in completed order.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

def add_one(number, n):
    return number + 1 + n

def process():
    all_numbers = []
    for i in range(0, 10):
        all_numbers.append(i)

    threads = []
    all_results = []
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        for number in all_numbers:
            threads.append(executor.submit(add_one, number))

        for index, task in enumerate(threads):
            result = task.result()
            #print(result)
            all_results.append(result)

    for index, result in enumerate(all_results):
        print(result)

process()
```

Answer (score 1):

Per @marlon's request, here is a variation of the @rorra solution that uses `itertools.repeat` to reduce some of the parameter passing complexity.

Example:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
import time
import itertools

def add_one(number, n):
    return number + 1 + n

def process():
    all_numbers = list(range(0, 10))

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        
        for result in executor.map(add_one, all_numbers, itertools.repeat(2)):
            print(result)

process()
```

Output:

```
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
```

Comment: what does the itertools.repeat(2) means? Why do you use repeat(2), instead of repeat(3)? How to make sure the 'n' in add_one to be correctly generated by repeat()?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat

Answer (score 0):

This can be one of the ways to get the desired result

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed


def add_one(number, index):
    return number + 1, index


def process():
    all_numbers = []
    for i in range(0, 10):
        all_numbers.append(i)

    threads = []
    all_results = []
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        for index, number in enumerate(all_numbers):
            threads.append(executor.submit(add_one, number, index))
        for task in as_completed(threads):
            result, index = task.result()
            all_results.append([result, index])
        all_results = sorted(all_results, key=lambda x: x[-1])

    for index, result in enumerate(all_results):
        print(result[0])


process()
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question was posted a some time ago, but I had a similar problem and I could sovle it creating a dict using the result of the method id() as key, and the chunk processed for the future function (in my case if one fails I need to try process this chunk one more time). Ex:

```
control_dict = {}
future = executor.submit(my_func, chunk))
control_dict[id(future)] = chunk
```

You could use the same strategy to "find" the order.